# can search engine searches content in query-string?

Tags: search, search-engine

My page URL is

`www.xyz.com/default.aspx?name=searching-my-new-code`

Is google reads name query-string "name" value in searching algorithm???

Suppose i am searching on google "searching my new code" at that time google searching algo code can read this value from my URL or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search engines can easily read and parse query strings so your URL would be indexed just fine.